# tz_convert in mysql always returns null even though time_zone tables are populated

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

let me be clear. I have googled this problem many times, and cannot find anything. initially I thought it was because I did not run the command

mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql

I ran it with the --force option as well to be sure, but no matter what, when i query tz_convert, i always get null back. Is there anything else I am missing that needs to be setup?

Comment: Please give us an example query that returns null for you.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'Pacific/Auckland','GMT'). that one would for example. I figured it out though! the command I ran

mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql

i was substituting the second mysql(after the -p) with the name of the target database i am working with, when in reality, mysql appears to keep a database itself called "mysql"! when I ran it with no substitutions just like that, it worked on all databases!

Comment: heh, yes, that would explain it.